# use variable value as array name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have numbers of a dynamically generated array in my script such as below:

```
var abc = {
    'Lorem' = 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Why' = 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Where' = 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

var def = {
     'Lore' = 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'hy' = 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Whre' = 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

var ghi = { 
    'Lrem' = 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Wh' = 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Were' = 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}
```

Now I need to get value from an array, I got the name of the array dynamically from a user and I store it in a variable like `array_name`.

I was trying to get value from variable like

```
var array_name = `abc`;
console.log(array_name['lorem']);
```

it gives me `undefined` as a response. Also, try to store value in `hidden field` and get value from `textbox`, but it hadn't work for me:

```
console.log(($('#array_name').val()['lorem']);
```

Please help me get value from array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly I don't really like to use `eval`, if your random variable are globally scoped you can access it with `window[array_name]['Lorem']`, otherwise if they are limited inside a function or similiar, I suggest you to use a different approach, something like

```
var randomVars = {};
randomVars.abc = {
    'Lorem': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Why' : 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Where' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

randomVars.def = {
     'Lore': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'hy' :'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Whre' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

randomVars.ghi = { 
    'Lrem' : 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Wh' : 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Were' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}
```

in this way you can call your text like `randomVars[array_name]['Lorem']`

Answer (score 1):

Dont assign array_name to a string.

```js
var abc = {
    'Lorem': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Why' : 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Where' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

var def = {
     'Lore': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'hy' :'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Whre' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

var ghi = { 
    'Lrem' : 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Wh' : 'but also the leap into electronic typesetting',
    'Were' : 'making it over 2000 years old.'
}

let new_name = abc
console.log(new_name['Lorem'])
```

Comment: The OP wants it to be a string, you are just referring to the obj. Since you say `Dont assign array_name to a string.` then why not just console.log(abc['Lorem'])

Comment: You can convert a string to object as well. @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a object to hold object `abc,def,...`, then [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) can be used to access the desired property using a *string*

```js
let obj = {
  abc: {
    'Lorem': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'
  },
  def: {
    'Lore': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'
  },
  ghi: {
    'Lrem': 'Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'
  }
}

console.log(obj['abc'])
```